# How to access properties from base class?

Tags: c#

Let's assume I have a class `Animal` and a subclass `Dog`. The subclass `Dog` has a property which the class `Animal` doesn't have (let's assume the property is `Age` and this property hasn't been defined in the `Animal` class before).

Now when I have:

```
Animal animal;
```

and later I recognize that my animal is a dog:

```
animal = new Dog();
```

How can I access the age of the dog now like:

```
int age = animal.Age;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `((Dog)animal).Age;`, but you should check if it's an animal first to avoid exceptions--not needed for super simple code, but this is one pattern: `if (animal is Dog
 )  { int age = ((Dog)animal).Age;  }`,

Comment: That, or polymorphism. Whatever is the reason for accessing `Age` gets encoded as an abstract method of `Animal`. You'd then override this in `Dog` and there have access to `Dog`'s properties (including `Age`). Let's say you're an animal trainer. So you're interested in whether a particular animal can be trained to do tricks: `partial abstract class Animal { public abstract bool CanBeTrainedToDoTricks { get; } }`. For dogs, that depends on their age: `sealed partial class Dog { public override bool CanBeTrainedToDoTricks => this.Age < 14; }`

Comment: @Quantic I believe `Dog` has the property `Age`, not `Animal`. So I believe you want to swap `Animal` with `Dog` in your code...

Comment: @Quantic is will throw exception... you should use as

Comment: Oops had it right he first time, thanks @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: `int age = (animal as Dog)?.Age ?? 0;`

Comment: for c# 6 and up int age = (animal as Dog)?.Age??-1;

Comment: @Quantic Thanks you solved my problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your `animal` back to a `Dog` to access the properties of it. You can do this safely with either:

- `as` with `null` check:

  ```
  Dog dog = animal as Dog;
  if (dog != null) { /*animal was Dog access properties here*/ }
  ```
- `is` with explicit cast:

  ```
  if (animal is Dog)
  {
      Dog dog = (Dog)animal;
  }
  ```

However, this downcasting looks like a code smell, you might need to consider a redesign.

Comment: There is no boxing or unboxing going on here since `Dog` is not a value type (and it can't be since it inherits from `Animal`).  This is just downcasting (which is still a code smell).

Comment: @Kyle Woops thats what I meant

Answer (score 0):

Simple cast it using `(Dog)animal`.

In these cases I like to use the `as` cast:

```
var probablyDog = animal as Dog;
if (probablyDog != null)
{
    //indeed dog
    probablyDog.Age;
}
```

if `probablyDog` is null, it is no dog or `animal` is null.